# Configurable Drop-down options in related products (related.phtml) - error Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object

Tags: configurable-product, class, object, related-products

I am trying to give the **related products** on each product page, the ability to show the **drop-down options of configurable products**; so that the user can select options and add to basket without navigating to the individual product's page.

I have copied the code from `configurable.phtml`, which loads the options on product pages of configurable products, into `related.phtml`, which loads the related products, but it gives this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a
>   non-object ... in line 76

I think it is the object `$_item` which is not the right class or something, and therefore the method `getSortedChildren()` does not work on it, but I am not sure how to access the right class or the right object so that the method can work.

Please, can anyone help, as this is essential for my website?

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-related">
<div class="block-title">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></h2>
</div>
<div class="block-content">          
    <ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li class="item">            
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(75) ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>


                <!-- Insert FORM here -->
                <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"<?php if($_item->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>> 
                    <?php if(!$_item->isGrouped()): ?> 
                        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_item)?$this->getMinimalQty($_item):1) ?>" /> 
                        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label> 
                    <?php endif; ?> 

                    <!-- Code copied from Configurable.phtml to get configurable options for related products-->
                    <div class="related-options-custom">
                        <?php if($_item->isConfigurable()) {

                            $_product    = $_item;
                            $_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
                            $_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
                            $_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();

                            ?>
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
                                <dl>
                                <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>

                                    <?php
                                    $_rendered = false;
                                    foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
                                        $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
                                        if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
                                            $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
                                            $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
                                            echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                                            $_rendered = true;
                                            break;
                                        endif;
                                    endforeach;

                                    if (!$_rendered):
                                    ?>

                                    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
                                    <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                                                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
                                    </dd>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </dl>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);
                                </script>

                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
                            <?php endif;                                    
                        }?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End of Configurable Code from configurable.phtml -->


                    <button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                </form>
                <!-- END OF FORM -->


            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>

</div>
```